# Position within the string of the characters that are comma

Tags: r, string

I am looking for a R code that, given a particular string, tells me the position within the string of the characters that are a comma.
For instance, if I provide the code with "11-540,11-541", I would like the code to return 7, as the comma is the 7th character in the string.

Thank you!